# $\int Q(b-cx) dx =?$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am unable to understand the following integral
$$
\int Q(b+cx) dx = \frac{1}{c}\left[(b+cx)Q(b+cx)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp\{-\frac{(b+cx)^2}{2}\}\right] .......(1)
$$

where Q(x) is defined as 
$$
Q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^\infty exp\{\frac{-y^2}{2}\}dy .....(2)
$$

I know how to solve the following integral 
$$
\int Q(x)dx=xQ(x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp\{\frac{-x^2}{2}\} ......(3)
$$

Actually i need to solve
$$
\int Q(b-cx)dx = ? ..... (4)
$$

but for that I must understant the first equation.

kindly help me,

cordially

Comment: Integration by substitution: in the known integral
$$
\int Q(u)du=uQ(u)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2}\right)
$$
use $u=b \pm cx$

Comment: @gammatester: can you elaborate a bit please. I shall be grateful

Comment: But if i replace $u=b+cx$, i dont end with the answer in equation (1) of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $d (b+cx)=c dx$

From (1) we obtain:

$$c\int Q(b+cx) dx=\int Q(b+cx) d(b+cx) =(b+cx)Q(b+cx)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(b+cx)^2}{2}\right) .......(2)$$

Set $u=b+cx$ we have

$$\int Q(u) du =u Q(u)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right) .......(3)$$

This is exactly what suggested by gammatester!

Similarly:
$d (b-cx)=-c dx$

$$-c\int Q(b-cx) dx=\int Q(b-cx) d(b-cx) =(b-cx)Q(b-cx)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(b-cx)^2}{2}\right) .......(4)$$

Comment: excellent Thank you very much @mike

Comment: @gammemaster : Thank you